# Passing extra options from a model to view

Tags: django

**Django 1.10**

I have created a wiki model. A wiki article will be attached to objects of **different** types. Below is example where I'm trying to attach a wiki to a Masterphoto object. Later a wiki will be attached to a Person instance or something. Well, wiki is supposed to be attachable to anything.

In Masterphoto the method get_create_wiki_url happily sends extra options to url dispatcher.

Well, then I fail.

If I do like this: url(r'^wiki/create/$', WikiCreate.as_view(), name='wiki_create'), then I get:

```
Reverse for 'wiki_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'model': 'masterphoto', 'pk': 4}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/create/$']
```

This works: url(r'^wiki/create/$', WikiCreate.as_view(), name='wiki_create', kwargs={'model': 'masterphoto', 'pk': 4}),

But this is ridiculous.

Could you give me a kick here? In other words, how to transmit extra options from a Masterphoto to the wiki_create view?

**wiki/models.py**

```
class Wiki(models.Model):
    related_model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    related_object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    article = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default="")
```

**masterphoto/models.py**

```
class Masterphoto(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_create_wiki_url(self):
        return reverse('wiki_create', kwargs = {'model': self._meta.app_label, 'pk': self.id})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^wiki/create/$', WikiCreate.as_view(), name='wiki_create', kwargs=None),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use named groups in your url definition to capture specific parts of the url and pass them as `kwargs` to the view ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)). In your case something like this should work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^wiki/create/(?P<model>\w+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', WikiCreate.as_view(), name='wiki_create'),
]
```

Comment: I don't like named groups in this case. Reason: the url looks terrible. I just don't understand why I can't use extra options in this case. Do I understand you correctly that it is impossible to transmit extra options?

Comment: Not using `reverse`, no. The `args` in `reverse` are mapped to groups in url pattern and `kwargs` to named groups in url pattern; there is no way to send extra options through `reverse`. I guess you'll have to use e.g. session variables if you don't want these params to appear in your urls.